# Re-enable load on demand [NativeScript Vue]

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, radlistview

I have a Radlistview, where the data switches out based on user query. With `loadOnDemandMode="Auto"` and when the current query is exhausted, I then call `notifyLoadOnDemandFinished(true)`. However, when a new query is made, I cannot re-enable loadOnDemand, and new items are not loaded.

Is there a way to reactivate loadOnDemand, perhaps with a method on the radListView object? I couldn't find anything in the docs.

Comment: It should work by default, whenever you reach end of scroll, it should call load more. Do you have a Playground sample?

Comment: It works great by default, my issue was attempting to disable and then re-enable the same listView with a new dataset. Was just missing the _nativeview object, as in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the mistake, posting here for anyone else that may have the problem.

I was trying to set

`listView.loadOnDemandMode = "Auto"`

adding `_nativeView` fixed it

`listView._nativeView.loadOnDemandMode = "Auto"`